# GeoTiff exported using GRASS will not open in other programs

Tags: grass-gis, export, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to export an image group as a multi-band GeoTiff using the r.out.gdal module in GRASS. For some reason I cannot get ArcGIS to recognize my GeoTiff exports. I have tried opening the file in Opticks and SAGA and neither of them can open it either. To simplify things, I generated a classification raster and tried to export this, with the same result that nothing recognizes it. I have tried playing with the module settings and adding createopt strings as recommended in the GRASS documentation for r.out.gdal, but nothing is working. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: What type of compression (if any) are you using? Does the output of `gdalinfo` for the created file indicate anything non-standard?

Comment: Including the whole gdalinfo report might help us in helping you.

Comment: What does _cannot get to recognise_ mean? Any error message?  Or simply a blank image?  Did you check for color-tables issues?  Did you check the statistics of the GeoTiFFs inside Arc*? Please, report the composition of the group itself (the group in GRASS-GIS' database) and the output of r.info for the raster maps that compose the group in question.

Comment: By cannot get to recognize I mean that ArcGIS and Opticks both do not show my GeoTiff exports as existing in the directory as it does with unsupported file types. In the directory from Windows Explorer it shows it as a "File" but does not recognize it as a .tif image. I am not specifying a compression type. No error messages on the GRASS side of things. During export I check the box to not write the color table. When I import these images back into GRASS they show up just fine. I wonder if r.out.gdal is automatically compressing the image somehow?

Comment: Can you double check that your region settings match the image group that you want to export? `g.region -p` and `r.info -g <one of your rasters that makes up the image group>`

Comment: I've double checked and the regions match up just fine. I've also tried exporting as HFA and NITF, and exporting different images, with the same result. None of my exports from GRASS appear to work in ArcGIS

Comment: I suspect you didn't add .tif extension to your file name: r.out.gdal input=myraster output=myraster.tif

Answer (score 1):

Adding a .tif extension to the file name solved the problem.